# How to make firefox open CLI app in specified terminal

Tags: linux, firefox, terminal

I have two terminals: uxterm and urxvt. I also use ranger as my file browser.
Whenever I select *Open Containing Folder* in *Firefox Downloads*, Firefox opens ranger in uxterm. How to make Firefox open ranger in urxvt instead of in uxterm without removing uxterm?

If I have installed another File Manager (I tried Thunar and PCManFM) Firefox automatically chooses them.

I also tried setting `$TERM` and `$TERMINAL` to `urxvt` and `rxvt-unicode-256color` but there is no difference.

I am running Arch Linux.

Comment: Change `/etc/alternatives/x-terminal-emulator`.

Comment: You should probably add which distribution you are running, as implementation of that may depend on the distribution. - For example, @IporSircer's reply is only valid on Ubuntu and Debian.

Comment: post is updated

Comment: Starting firefox from terminal and then clicking on "Open Containing Folder" in Downloads shows message: `(firefox:6915): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: couldn't find a terminal, falling back to xterm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I solved this problem:

1. Copy the system `ranger.desktop` file to local folder.

   ```
   $ sudo cp /usr/share/applications/ranger.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
   ```
2. Change owner and group.

   ```
   $ sudo chown $USER ~/.local/share/applications/ranger.desktop && chgrp 
   $USER ~/.local/share/applications/ranger.desktop
   ```
3. Change *Terminal* to *false* and *Exec* to *urxvt -e ranger*

   ```
   $ sed -i 's/Terminal=true/Terminal=false/g' 
   ~/.local/share/applications/ranger.desktop && sed -i 
   's/Exec=ranger/Exec=urxvt -e ranger/g' 
   ~/.local/share/applications/ranger.desktop
   ```
4. Update desktop database

   ```
   $ update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications
   ```

Comment: Trilby provided better solution: [Trilby's post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1750727#p1750727).

Answer (score 2):

Create a desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications` like this example `file.desktop` in which I set folders to open with `vifm` running in the `st` terminal emulator:

```
    [Desktop Entry]
    Type=Application
    Name=File Manager
    Exec=/usr/local/bin/st -e vifm %u
```

Then update your `.config/mimeapps.list` file to use the new desktop file:

```
    inode/directory=file.desktop
```

Answer (score 1):

So here the terminal emulator comes from your Desktop Environment, probably GNOME. Just set your default there (go to the overview and look for 'Default Applications').

With non-DE WMs, you need to look up what your WM does. In the case of `i3`, it uses the [i3-sensible-terminal](https://build.i3wm.org/docs/i3-sensible-terminal.html) wrapper.

Since you used the `$TERMINAL` variable: did you set it in `.xinitrc` or whatever you used to start the `i3`.

For background, `/usr/share/applications/ranger.desktop` only says `Terminal=true` and lets the Desktop Environment figure out which terminal to use.

Comment: I don't have DE.

Comment: Okay, so what does `xdg-mime query default inode/directory` return?

Comment: `ranger.desktop`

Comment: My bad, that was a stupid question. What WM are you running? And do you have some kind of settings daemon (i.e. gnome-settings-daemon) active?

Comment: i3wm. No, `systemctl list-units` doesn't show anything containing "settings" or "preferences".

Comment: Also, `xdg-mime query default applications/x-terminal-emulator` outputs `urxvt.desktop`.

Comment: I tried putting `export TERMINAL=urxvt` in `.bashrc`.

Comment: Just tried in `.i3/config` and no results.

Comment: `i3-sensible-terminal` is urxvt, I just did `i3-msg exec i3-sensible-terminal`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Firefox uses Gio which check for the existence of several specific terminals in `$PATH`. See this:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/blob/2.21.6/gio/gdesktopappinfo.c#L773

As you can read, `rxvt-unicode-256color` and `$TERMINAL` are not checked. Hence the solution, is to create an executable named (e.g) `rxvt` and make sure Firefox finds it in **his** `$PATH`.

You can find out Firefox' `$PATH` via

```
grep -z '^PATH=' /proc/$(pidof -s firefox)/environ | tr ':' '\n'
```

Run this command while Firefox is running. Usually, `/usr/local/bin` is gonna be printed there, but not any PATH you add in your *shell* startup files (i.e `.bashrc`).

For example, here's a command that makes `termite` available as `rxvt` in `$PATH`:

```
sudo ln -s $(which termite) /usr/local/bin/rxvt
```

Change `termite` with the terminal of your choice.

The idea is, that when Firefox is searching for one of the executables it is aware of, (the executables in the switch case [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/blob/2.21.6/gio/gdesktopappinfo.c#L773)), it will find an executable `rxvt` in it's `$PATH` and it won't know it's actually a symlink to `termite`.

Credit: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1750642#p1750642